# Hit the api when edittext is populated with date android

Tags: android

i am working in a project in which i will be using a edittext which opens up a DatepickerDialog on clicking it.

My requirement is i have hit the api once the date gets populated in the edittext.
How to achieve this?

The code i used

```
public bool_editTextToDate=false;

editText_toDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickedEditText = 2;
                new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

                bool_editTextToDate = true;

        });




 editText_toDate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (bool_editTextToDate&& !editText_toDate.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "HitAPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // TO HIT API HERE
                    bool_editTextToDate=false;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

I have played like this.Can i have to use onFocusChangeListener to acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` to get the callback when date is set on the dialog.
refer this link for more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

sample code:

```
    public SomeClass implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { 

    void someMethod(){

    editText_toDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickedEditText = 2;
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                     datePickerDialog.setOnDateSetListener(SomeClass.this); 
                     datePickerDialog.show();
                    bool_editTextToDate = true;

            });
       //Touch listener not needed.

        }

      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
           //  HIT API HERE Based on data.
      }
    }
```

Comment: i have clearly written you need to pass `SomeClass.this` if your `SomeClass implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`,
Replace `SomeClass` with your own